# DOM Not updated while using ng-click in function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-show

I am using a simple code. When click Login link, its div should hide. I am updating ng-show value for hiding.
While clicking, the ng-show value is updated to "false" but the DIV is not Hidden

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <Title>Weather</Title>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./app.js"></script>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" ng-controller="headerController">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                Weather
              </a>
            </div>
              <div class="navbar navbar-right" ng-show={{loginStatus}}><a ng-click="onLogin()">login</a></div>
          </div>
        </nav>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="headerController">{{name}}</div>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('headerController',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.name="Christo";
    $scope.loginStatus=true;
    $scope.onLogin = function(){
        $scope.loginStatus=false;
        console.log($scope.loginStatus);
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-show={{loginStatus}}` should be replaced with `ng-show="loginStatus"`.
`ngShow` directive automatically evaluates expression, so you should not use interpolation here. More about this [in docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

Answer (score 0):

You have to place {{loginStatus}} in scope controller headerController. Try moving {{loginStatus}} for to div controller

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `{{}}` for the `ng-show` attribute, as it already accepts an expression. If an attribute needs curly braces it is marked as `{template}` in the docs and when it doesn't - as `{expression}`.

Compare parameters for:

`ngShow` - doesn't need curly: [Refer](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngShow)

`ngSrc` - needs curly: [Refer](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc)

And also please refer [Understanding angular templates](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates)